# OpenGL depth test not working as expected

Tags: opengl

I have a simple program to use depth test.   It is not working as expected.   The program draws X, Y axis and a sphere near the origin.
If I don't turn on the GL_DEPTH_TEST, the sphere is drawn over the axis.   If I turn on the GL_DEPTH_TEST, the axis are drawn over the sphere which I was not expecting.   Can someone tell me what I did
wrong ?

```
void  
glwid::initializeGL()  
{    
    glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);      
}  



void  
glwid::resizeGL(int width, int height)  
{  
    glViewport( 0, 0, (GLint)width, (GLint)height );  
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );  
    glLoadIdentity();  

    gluPerspective ( 90, (GLint)width/ (GLint)height, 0.0, 200.0 );  
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );  
    glLoadIdentity();  
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);  
}  


void  
glwid::paintGL()  
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  

    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);  
    glLoadIdentity();  

    gluLookAt (0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);  


    //  
    // X axis  
    //  
    glBegin( GL_LINES );  
    qglColor( green );  
    glVertex3f (-100.0,  0, 0. );  
    glVertex3f (100.0, 0, 0. );  
    glEnd();  


    //  
    // Y axis  
    //  
    glBegin( GL_LINES );  
    qglColor( red );  
    glVertex3f (0.0, 100.0, 0. );  
    glVertex3f (0.0, -100, 0. );   
    glEnd();  

    //  
    // sun  
    //  
    glTranslated (5, 0, 20);  
    GLUquadricObj *sphere_quadric = gluNewQuadric();  
    glColor3ub (255, 255, 0);  
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(sphere_quadric, (GLenum)GLU_SMOOTH);  
    gluSphere(sphere_quadric, 10, 36, 36);  
}
```

Comment: No one is going to answer it like this. Fix the formatting.

Comment: Could you post pictures with/without the depth test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've tried your code. The problem is in `resizeGL()` function.
The problem was your putting to

```
gluPerspective ( 90, (GLint)width/ (GLint)height, 0.0, 200.0 );
```

0.0 value as a third argument. Put 0.01 for example - and everything will be ok. that's because this parameter should always be positive:
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml

Also change `(GLint)width/ (GLint)height` to `(GLfloat)width/ (GLfloat)height` otherwise the result will be strange.

And it's better to put `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` into `initializeGL()` function

Comment: glEnable belongs not into initialization. Every OpenGL state is to be set right before you need it. glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) belongs into paintGL right before the geometry is drawn. Also glViewport, setting the projection matrix and the other stuff belongs there and nowhere else.

Comment: I mean the resize() method is not a good place and for this program it's enough to put glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) into initialization because it's not being changed anywhere. But globally you're right

Comment: Thank you Andrew, the perpective parameter was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your axis starts at Z location 0. The Sphere is at Z location 20 (farther away from the "camera") therefore the axis is in-front of the sphere and is being shown.

As you currently have it setup, as Z values go up they move away from the screen. As they go down, they are going closer to the screen.

You have two options: Disable depth testing while drawing your axis (therefore it will always be behind everything). Or move your axis to Z position 100 or so and scale it up to make it look the same size. Option one is probably better.

Simply wrapping your axis drawing routines in `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` and `glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);`  should do the trick

Comment: the camera is at (0, 0, 100). Axis origing - (0, 0, 0) sphere center - (5, 0, 20). Axis are farther

Comment: I missed the camera placement line. Good catch.

Comment: Depth test must work automatically! You should not enable/disable when it just should work! - it's the same as doing manually object sorting - the thing depth test should do

Comment: 'You should not enable/disable when it just should work! ' true but there's many times when adding/disabling depth testing is the correct thing to do.